# Horizontal Submanifolds of Maximal Dimension

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields, submanifold

Briefly, my question is, what algorithms or techniques exist for determining the maximal *dimension* of an integral submanifold of a non-integrable distribution?

The Heisenberg Group $ \mathbb{H}_n $ is the "simplest" example of a subriemannian manifold.  It can be presented as $ \mathbb{R}^{2n+1} $ (with coordinates $ (x_1, y_1, \ldots, x_n, y_n, t) $) equipped with the horizontal distribution $ H \mathbb{H}_n = \ker(\alpha) $ where $ \alpha $ is the one-form
$$
\alpha = dt + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i\, dy_i}
$$
One can show that, for $ k \geq n+1 $, every (say, smooth) $ k $-form $ \kappa $ can be decomposed as
\begin{equation}\label{decomp}\tag{1}
\kappa = \alpha \wedge \sigma + d \alpha \wedge \tau
\end{equation}
for suitable (smooth) forms $ \sigma $ and $ \tau $.  It therefore follows that there do not exist smooth horizontal embeddings $ f : \mathbb{R}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}_n $ for such $ k $.  By horizontal, we mean, $ f^* \alpha = 0 $.  Indeed, if $ f : \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{H}_n $ is any smooth map, then \eqref{decomp} implies $ f^* \kappa = 0 $ for any $ k $-form $ \kappa $, whence $ f $ has rank $ \text{rank}{(Df)} < k $.  This example shows that not only is the $ 2n $-dimensional horitontal distribution $ H \mathbb{H} $ not *integrable*, but in fact, there are not even $ (n+1) $-dimensional horizontal submanifolds (!)

Proving this fact was not easy, essentially because it was not very easy to prove \eqref{decomp}.  All I found was a long, elementary combinatorial argument.  I am aware of the fact that an $m$-dimensional distribution is *integrable* - i.e., has $ m $-dimensional integral manifolds - but I am not aware of how one looks for maximal submanifolds of a *non-integrable* distribution such as $ H \mathbb{H}_n $ above.  Some nice pointers I am looking for include:

1. An theorem (or better yet, an algorithm) to calculate the maximum dimension of an integral submanifold of a distribution $ HM \subseteq TM $ in the tangent space of a manifold $ M $ (presented as a span of vector fields or as the intersection of kernels of one-forms).
2. An example of a distribution distinct from the Heisenberg groups $ \mathbb{H}_n $ exhibiting this non-integrability.  In fact, let's introduce the following terminology: let's say that a distribution is $ k $-integrable if it has $ k $-dimensional, but not $ (k+1) $-dimensional, integral submanifolds.  For what pairs $ (m,k) $ can we construct an $ m $-dimensional $ k $-integrable distribution on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ ($ n > m $)?
3. References in which these or related questions are systematically studied.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of **exterior differential systems** was essentially designed to answer exactly these sorts of questions, and much of the theory is algorithmic.

I don't have time to give detailed thought to your question, I'm afraid, but can point you to two standard references on the subject:

(1) [Nine Lectures on Exterior Differential Systems](https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/Introduction_to_EDS.pdf) by Bryant.

(2) [Exterior Differential Systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461397168) by Bryant, Chern, Gardner, Goldschmidt, and Griffiths.

Chapter II of reference (2) is especially relevant to your question.  Key words you might want in searching for more literature: The Pfaff Theorem (or Pfaff-Darboux Theorem), Pfaffian Systems, Cartan-Kahler Theory.